# Is there a pythonic way to add a text description to instance objects?

Tags: python

I think it is best to explain what I want by giving the way I'm currently doing it:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, vehicle):
        self.vehicle = vehicle

    def set_driver_temperament(self, text):
        self._driver_temperament = text

    def get_driver_temperament(self):
        return self._driver_temperament


driver1 = Car('Toyota Camry')
# A lot of code here
driver1.set_driver_temperament("""
        Cool Headed
        Financial Wise""")

driver2 = Car('Ferrari')
# A lot of code here
driver2.set_driver_temperament("""
        A**hole
        Too much money, too little brains""")
```

I just want to know if there is a more pythonic way of doing this? I checked online, but I cannot find anything

Edit:

So the example is not too clear, but the `driver_temperament` can not be set at the initial declaration.

Comment: Yes. Don't use a getter and a setter and just use a regular attribute `driver_temperment` with no underscores

Comment: Driver temperament should also probably be created in `__init__` and be an argument to the constructor

Comment: Why do you think the text description should be treated any differently than the vehicle name?

Comment: Hmmm, I would've done it like that. But with the way my code is set up, the `driver_tempermant` can only be set much later in the code.

Comment: Or you could track the different aspects of temperament as different variables and define a `__str`__` that combines them appropriately; depends on what your goal is.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that is what I was looking for. If you make it into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm not sure that the question specifies enough details to make that answer follow from its contents. I'm glad the suggestion was helpful to you, but unless you can clarify the question to make it more clear, I tend to think it's probably better closed than answered.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. No worries, I voted for it to be closed then.